# Calling a function from a reloaded DLL hangs the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, dll

In my C# app I'm using an open source library that loads an unmanaged DLL and calls some functions from it.

1. First I call `var instance = lib.CreateInstance("R.dll")` which loads the DLL using `LoadLibrary` from `kernel32.dll`
2. Then I call `instance.init()` which calls some function from the loaded DLL

It works fine if I run the code as a **console app**, but when I integrated the code into an **ASP.NET** web app it hangs during the second run. As far as I understand it the web server (IIS) uses one process to handle many requests so the DLL is already loaded when `var instance = lib.CreateInstance("R.dll")` is called for the second time.

**How can I make it work on the server? Is there a way to unload the DLL after each request to the server?**

Answer (score 0):

Loading and unloading a dll for every request isn't a very good idea. You would slow down your responses quite a lot. If you need it for every request, load it just once.

Since you don't control what `lib.CreateInstance("R.dll")` does, you could keep the instance in a singleton class and use CreateInstance only if it has not already been loaded.

Jon Skeet has a [nice article on thread safe singletons](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/singleton.html).

Comment: My code is inside `class MyClass { public int MyFunc() {var instance = lib.CreateInstance("R.dll");}}` at the beggining of a new server request a new instance of MyClass is created. How do I save a referene to `instance` between requests?

Comment: Your instance would have to be a static member of your class. That way it will persist even after your object is destroyed. A static member would be shared across all objects of your class. This is the singleton pattern. Do take a look at the linked article, if you want a good implementation. It explains the pattern well.